# Regular expressions string replacement of individual match within file

Tags: regex, vb.net, expression

I have written a small program to whir through a textfile and find and replace `regex` where 9 digits `\d{9}`. It works fine, except what I need is a little more complicated.

I am finding the right data correctly. `theFile` is just a string with the text file streamread into it. I do this and then create and write it to another file.

But I need to find each string match individually, and replace that match with only the last 5 digits of that individual number (currently this is just replacing with FOUND). Keeping the file otherwise identical.

I am not sure how/what is the best way of doing this? would i have to split into an array of strings rather than one mass string? (it's quite a big file)

Any questions let me know, thanks in advance.

```
Dim regexString As String = "(\d{9})"
Dim replacement1 As String = "FOUND"
Dim rgx As New Regex(regexString)

Try
   theFile = rgx.Replace(theFile, replacement1)
Catch

End try
```

Comment: Try `regexString = "\d{4}(\d{5})"` and `replacement1 ="\1"` (or `replacement1 ="$1"` as I am not sure what VB uses). There may be additional options (parameters) to `rgx.Replace(...)` for replace once versus replace all occurrences.

Comment: What should happen with a string that contains 10 (or more) numbers? Like "0123456789"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using just one replacement pattern `\d{9}` split and group with two patterns, the first is 4 numbers long, the second 5 numbers. Then in the replace use only the last 5 numbers from the last group

```
Dim k = "abcd 123456789 abcf"
Dim ptn = "(\d{4})(\d{5})"
Dim result = Regex.Replace(k, ptn, "$2")
```

This approach leaves unchanged the sequences with less than 9 consecutive numbers, but if you have sequences with more than 9 numbers and don't want to change them, then you need a pattern with

```
Dim ptn = "(\b\d{4})(\d{5}\b)"
```

to fix the two groups inside a sequence of exactly nine numbers.

Comment: Last 5, not first five.

Comment: Uhm, doesn't work if the string is 10 numbers long. Need to ask the OP what he/she expects to do with a string with 10 (or more) numbers

Comment: As I read the question, it only applies to 9 digit numbers. However, using `ptn = "(\d{4,})(\d{5})"` or `ptn = "(\d\d\d\d+)(\d{5})"` or `ptn = "(\d\d\d\d\d*(\d{5})"` should work for longer numbers. The `\d{5}` should always match the final 5 digits but it may be worth using `...(\d{5})([^\d]|$)"` and changing the replace to be `$2$3`. That way it looks for a trailing non-digit or end-of-string. (By the way there is no need to wrap the opening digits in capture brackets.)

Comment: @AdrianHHH, I think that you have a good answer here, don't esitate to post it also if it is similar to another one.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for this, don't know why it didn't occur to me, will try these all now. 10 etc numbers should theoretically never happen, but I'm thinking I'll catch it or something if it does, but when it does it's technically just rubbish data and I just need to warn and drop it.

Answer (score 1):

The question appears to ask for matches on exactly nine digits and wants the first four to be removed. Ie to replace the nine digits with the last five.

Splitting the regular expression in the question into two parts, for the unwanted and the wanted parts gives

```
 regexString = "\d{4}(\d{5})"
```

which captures the wanted five digits, so then the replacement is

```
replacement1 ="$1"
```

Or in some other regular expression implementations it would be `replacement1 ="\1"`. Additionally the replace method in some regular expression system may have additional options (parameters) for replace first versus replace n-th versus replace all occurrences.

---

Suppose there are more than nine digits and only the final five are wanted. In this case the regular expression can be written as one of the following (as different regular expression languages support different features). The replacement expression is the same as above.

```
 regexString = "\d{4,}(\d{5})"
 regexString = "\d\d\d\d+(\d{5})"
 regexString = "\d\d\d\d\d*(\d{5})"
```

Because regular expressions are normally "greedy" the `\d{5}` should always match the final 5 digits but it may be worth finishing the regular expression with `...(\d{5})([^\d]|$)` and changing the replace to be `$1$2`. That way it looks for a trailing non-digit or end-of-string.